# Instantiate generic type with constructor arguments?

Tags: java, inheritance, types

I'm facing a very confusing problem right now.

I am developing an extension for a program library. In said library, there are multiple classes *A, B, C and D*, which all inherit from the same superclass *Base*.

Now, I'm making individual extensions for each of those classes, *A1, B1, C1 and D1*, which all inherit from *A, B, C and D* respectively. In addition to that, they all implement a custom interface *I1*, which I have also added myself.

The constructor for base (and all child classes, including mine) accepts one argument of the type *E*.

In order to instantiate those classes in an easy manner, I'm trying to write a handler class that creates an instance when needed. It's supposed to work something like this:

```
public class Handler
{
    private Base ctype;
    public Handler(Class<T extends Base implements I1> ctype)
    {
          this.ctype = new ctype.class(E.instance);
    }
}
```

Now, of course it doesn't work that way, but I'm sure I got the idea across.

As of right now, I have a working version of my extension, albeit very sloppy, because instead of a handler class, I'm checking for every type manually and instantiating the proper Object. As I will have to modify many more classes in the future, I'd like to avoid that at all costs, to avoid file clutter.

I'm aware of the ctype.newInstance() method, however since the Base class requires a parameter in its constructor, I'm afraid it won't work. (unless I'm missing something, in which case please point me to it!)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use for example [`getConstructor(Class...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) to get a constructor which is other than the default no-argument one.

You'd have something like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Handler<B extends Base & I1> {
    private E instanceOfE = ...; // Not sure where you get the E from.
    private Constructor<B> ctor;

    public Handler(Class<B> ctype) {
        if (Modifier.isAbstract(ctype.getModifiers())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ctype + " is abstract");
        }
        if (!Modifier.isPublic(ctype.getModifiers())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ctype + " is not public");
        }
        try {
            ctor = ctype.getConstructor(E.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException x) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(x);
        }
        Arrays.stream(ctor.getExceptionTypes())
              .filter(x -> !RuntimeException.class.isAssignableFrom(x)
                        && !Error.class.isAssignableFrom(x))
              .findFirst()
              .ifPresent(x -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(ctor + " declares a checked exception");
    }

    private B create() {
        try {
             return ctor.newInstance(instanceOfE);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException x) {
             Throwable cause = x.getCause();
             if (cause instanceof RuntimeException)
                 throw (RuntimeException) cause;
             if (cause instanceof Error)
                 throw (Error) cause;
             // This won't happen because we checked for
             // it in the constructor.
             throw new RuntimeException(cause);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException
               | InstantiationException x) {
             // These also won't happen because we checked
             // for it in the constructor.
             throw new RuntimeException(x);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm not all that convinced you need to use reflection. You can use lambda expressions and method references to do this sort of thing now and it's generally much better.

Instead of passing a class, you'd pass some sort of an `Function<E, Base>`:

```
public class Handler<B extends Base & I1> {
    public Handler(Function<E, B> ctorFn) {
        Base b = ctorFn.apply(instanceOfE);
    }
}
```

And then you create new handlers with a method reference:

```
Handler<A1> h = new Handler<>(A1::new);
```

Reflection is fine and very powerful but it's not always the best way for this sort of thing nowadays.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I hope others in my place will find this post as useful as I did.

Comment: I did find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

To call a constructor that takes arguments, use [`getConstructor(Class<?>...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) to get a `Constructor`. `Constructor` has a `newInstance()` method that takes arguments.

```
this.ctype = ctype.getConstructor(E.class).newInstance(E.instance);
```

Exception handling is left as an exercise for the reader.